# Pycharm visual warning about unresolved attribute reference

Tags: python, pycharm

I have two classes that look  like this:

```
class BaseClass:

    def the_dct(self):
        return self.THE_DCT


class Kid(BaseClass):

    THE_DCT = {'key': 'value'}


# Code i ll be running
inst = Kid()
print(inst.the_dct())
```

Inheritance has to be this way; second class containing `THE_DCT` and first class containing `def the_dct`.

It works just fine, but my problem is that I get a warning in PyCharm (unresolved attribute reference), about `THE_DCT` in `BaseClass`.

- Is there a reason why it's warning me (as in why I should avoid it)?
- Is there something I should do differently?

Comment: *"Is there a reason why it's warning me?"* - because **in the `BaseClass`** there is no `THE_DCT`. *"Is there something i should do differently?"* - you could include an empty dictionary `THE_DCT = {}` in `BaseClass`, or just ignore the warning.

Comment: PyCharm often warns things that will work, there are limits to how good code inspection can be (often due to budget and time...).

Comment: @Scironic this specific implementation will work, but PyCharm is warning because e.g. `BaseClass().the_dct()` will fail.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So there is no real danger from simply ignoring it. Correct?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's what I mean, the code can be fine, but PyCharm think's it is wrong - a limit of the program.

Comment: @user5061 as long as it works properly (and is readable), there is no real danger.

Comment: @user5061 so long as you *clearly document* that `BaseClass` shouldn't be instantiated directly, this won't be a problem. You could also look into [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Within `BaseClass` you reference `self.THE_DCT`, yet when PyCharm looks at this class, it sees that `THE_DCT` doesn't exist.

Assuming you are treating this as an Abstract Class, PyCharm doesn't know that that is your intention. All it sees is a class accessing an attribute, which doesn't exist, and therefore it displays the warning.

Although your code will run perfectly fine (as long as you never instantiate `BaseClass`), you should really change it to:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    THE_DCT = {}

    def the_dct(self):
        return self.THE_DCT
```

Comment: _you should really change it to_ What problems might i have if i dont change it? 

Also, would defining `THE_DCT` in `BaseClass` reduce performance (perhaps a tiny reduction) unnecessarily?

Comment: This has nothing to do with performance. Don't ever write bad code because of "performance."

Comment: i understand that i should avoid optimizing prematurely but i m curious as to whether it will have an effect (even a tiny one) or not. 

PS: (my performance related question is irrelevant of my Topic question)

Comment: Yes. Do not write code that relies on inheritance to find undefined variables. It is very bad practice. Define the variables as placeholders and comment how inheritance will replace such definition. @Fermiparadox

Comment: This causes a class level (aka static) attribute to be added to the base class as well as the instance attribute. In addition to this being wasteful, since the class level attribute should not be used, it is error prone since you now have two objects on the same object with different values (compare `self.THE_DCT` and in a `@classmethod` you have `cls.THE_DCT` or in a regular method `self.__classs__.THE_DCT`).

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the existing answers, or as an alternative, you can use `Type Hints`. This satisfies PyCharm's warnings and also distinguishes the attribute as being inherited (or at least not native to the class). It's as simple as adding `THE_DCT: dict` at the very top of your class (before anything else).

```
class BaseClass(object):
    THE_DCT: dict  # Add a type-hint at the top of the class, before anything else

    def the_dct(self):
        return self.THE_DCT


class Kid(BaseClass):
    THE_DCT = {'vars': 'values'}
```

I prefer this approach because it negates the need to unnecessarily add a placeholder attribute (`self.THE_DCT = {}`) and, because it's visually different than declaring an attribute, it can also negate the need for adding a comment next to the placeholder attribute to explain that it's inherited.

Comment: I agree that type hints are the best way to handle these warnings.

Comment: Definitely more elegant in today's python 3 world.

Answer (score -1):

> Inheritance has to be this way; second class containing THE_DCT and first class containing def the_dct.

I'd say this is conceptually wrong: a base class cannot use (know about) fields(methods) in a subclass.

The fact that this works in Python is mind-boggling. :)