# How to avoid warnings when get subclass attribute with type checking in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
class Base(object):
    ...


class SubA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ...
        ...


class SubB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b1 = ...
        self.b2 = ...
        ...


def func(obj: Base):
    if type(obj) is SubA:
        obj.a  # do something with obj.a
    elif type(obj) is SubB:
        obj.b1  # do something with obj.b1
        obj.b2  # do something with obj.b2
    ...
```

then I got warnings at `func` from `PyCharm`:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'a' for class 'Base'
Unresolved attribute reference 'b1' for class 'Base'
Unresolved attribute reference 'b2' for class 'Base'
```

I have checked the type of `obj`, so I'm sure that my code is no problem to run.

How can I code to avoid such warnings?

Comment: A good answer for same question: [Pycharm visual warning about unresolved attribute reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28172255/7918293)

Comment: @niko , If I define attrs at base class, getting `obj.b1` or `obj.b2` when `obj` is `SubA ` would no warning too. But it will err when run.