# Get the current index of a combobox in pysimplegui?

Tags: python, indexing, combobox, pysimplegui

I have a combobox with options that are gathered from a SQLite table, and I am trying to get the index from this combobox when the user selects an option. I have tried to use it like a table but to no avail... It seems that combo boxes have an Index in Pysimplegui because you can use update(set_to_index=), but I can't seem to find a way to access it anywhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Combo.get` method if needed, but you really shouldn't need it as the `values` dictionary provides the same data.

Here's how to get the index using the `values` variable.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

choices = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
layout = [  [sg.Combo(choices, k='-COMBO-')],
            [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Go':
        if values['-COMBO-'] in choices:
            idx = choices.index(values['-COMBO-'])
            print(f'Index = {idx}')
        else:
            print('Selection not in choices')

window.close()
```

[image]

Here's the `get` method in use.  You can also simply use `values['-COMBO-']`
It will return the current value.  You can then use that to look up the "index" from the original choices.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

choices = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
layout = [  [sg.Combo(choices, k='-COMBO-')],
            [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Go':
        current = window['-COMBO-'].get()
        if current in choices:
            idx = choices.index(current)
            print(f'Index = {idx}')
        else:
            print('Selection not in choices')

window.close()
```

Comment: This solution will not work if the combo box has items with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

There's no method provided for it now in PySimpleGUI.

With tkinter method `current`, you can get the index of the current entry text in the values list, or `-1` if the current entry text is not in the values list.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
layout = [
    [sg.Combo(data, size=20, enable_events=True, key='COMBO')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Check')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ('COMBO', 'Check'):
        index = window['COMBO'].widget.current()
        print(index)

window.close()
```

Comment: Why does pycharm says: Unresolved attribute reference 'current' for class 'Widget'?

Comment: Maybe Pycharm cannot find what's the type for`window['COMBO'].widget` ? Try using `Type Hints` in the code.

Comment: May be a pycharm problem as Jason has (Type) hinted at (sorry for the bad pun) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172008/pycharm-visual-warning-about-unresolved-attribute-reference